# If Banach space is countable union of closed sets, Can I conclude space should be one of the closed set?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be Banach space. $F_n$ be closed subsets of X. If $X = \cup F_n$, Can I conclude $X = F_{n_0}$ for some $n_0$? If right, suggest a hint.

Comment: No. You can’t. The obvious example is that $\mathbb{R}$ is the reunion of the $[-n,n]$. What you can say, however, is that the reunion of the interiors of the $F_n$ is dense.

Comment: You can have at most that there is $n_0$ such that $F_{n_0}$ has non-empty interior (Baire category theorem).

Comment: Another thing that is true:  If $X$ is a Banach space, and $X = \bigcup F_n$ where $F_n$ are closed linear subspaces, then $X=F_{n_0}$ for some $n_0$.  Again, proof uses the Baire category theorem.

Comment: @GEdgar The statement you made is what I was thinking. Can you give some hint? How to proceed?

Comment: Should Fn be subspaces? cant we work with subsets? @GEdgar

Answer (score 1):

Proof in case the $F_n$ are closed linear subspaces.  Assume $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n = X$.  Since $X$ is a complete metric space, by the Baire category theorem $X$ is not the union of a countably many closed sets with empty interior.  Therefore, there is $n_0$ so that $F_{n_0}$ has nonempty interior.

There is $x_0 \in F_{n_0}$ and $r_0 > 0$ so that $F_{n_0} \supseteq B_{r_0}(x_0) := \{x : \|x-x_0\| < r_0\}$.  Since $F_{n_0}$ is closed under substraction, $F_{n_0} \supseteq B_{r_0}(x_0) - x_0 = B_{r_0}(0)$.  Then, since $F_{n_0}$ is closed under scalar multiples, $F_{n_0} \supseteq X$.

Answer (score 0):

If $(X,d)$ is unbounded, select $y\in X$ and consider $F_n=\{x\in X\,:\, d(x,y)\le n\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbb R =(-\infty,0]\cup[0,\infty).$$